# Crashlytics multiple environments and organisation for iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

In our application, we have four configurations debug, development, staging, and production. We have to create organization and added the app. I have followed this below link :
[Fabric Crashlytics multiple environments for iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149253/fabric-crashlytics-multiple-environments-for-ios-app)

```
1.  add custom user-defined setting to the Build Settings, e.g. MY_CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY and MY_CRASHLYTICS_BUILD_SECRET
2.  replace concrete APIKey in Info.plist under Fabric group with ${MY_CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY}
3.  add respective API Keys and Build Secrets from organisations you have created per the environment to Build Settings under the key from Step 1
4.  change the script in Run Script phase to be something like the below
```

But When I tried the fifth point in reference link to add the app in mac widget my app is not available. How to add apps? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Have you pressed the _+ New App_ button on the Mac app?

Comment: No. Is this possible to select the new app for same bundle id?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the same bundle identifier (com.mycompany.myapp) for all configurations?

Comment: yes, I want the same bundle for development and staging.